# SpriteKit - Sequencing multiple SKActions running on multiple SKNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I understand quite well the SKAction API but I cannot achieve to have good code when running sequential code on multiple nodes.

Here is a sample code (simplified) :

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    weak var node1: SKNode!
    weak var node2: SKNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        cacheUI()
        runSampleSequence()
    }

    private func cacheUI() {
        // Fetch nodes from associated SKS file
        node1 = self.childNode(withName: "node1")!
        node2 = self.childNode(withName: "node2")!
    }

    private func runSampleSequence() {
        // I want node1 to fadeIn
        // then node2 to fadeIn
        // then node1 to fadeOut
        // then node2 to fadeOut
        node1.run(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1),
            SKaction.run { [weak self] in
                self.node2.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2))
            },
            SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 4),
            SKaction.run { [weak self] in
                self.node2.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 3))
            }
        ]))
    }
}
```

The previous code will run perfectly, but will result with boilerplate code if we add node3, node4 ... I would like to be able to refactor it to be easier to read and maintain given specifications. Something like :

```
// Does not compile
self.run(SKAction.sequence([
    node1.fadeIn(withDuration: 1),
    node2.fadeIn(withDuration: 2),
    node1.fadeOut(withDuration: 4),
    node2.fadeOut(withDuration: 3)
]))
```

Can I achieve this ? I want the business code to appear as clear as possible.

How does SKAction.sequence(_:) behave exactly when using SKAction.run { _ }, does the next action is guarantee to be ran after the last SKAction.run block's instruction executes (and what if it itself perform asynchronous calls) ?

Bonus question: Am I right to set self as weak in closure capture lists ? As I do not want it to be kept as a strong reference when dismissing the game scene.

**EDITED:**
Well, something like that could do the job but the second fade starts before the first one ends ...

```
private func runSampleSequence() {
    // I want node1 to fadeIn
    // then node2 to fadeIn
    // then node1 to fadeOut
    // then node2 to fadeOut
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([
        node1.fadeIn(withDuration: 1),
        node2.fadeIn(withDuration: 2),
        node1.fadeOut(withDuration: 4),
        node2.fadeOut(withDuration: 3)
    ]))
}
```

by returning actions from an SKNode extension :

```
extension SKNode {
    func fadeIn(withDuration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        let action = SKAction.run {
            self.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: withDuration))
        }
        return action
    }
    //TODO: Extend for each base SKAction ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I achieve this ? I want the business code to appear as clear as
>   possible.

You can use swift extensions to make your code more readable. For example:

```
extension SKNode {

    //TODO: Rename method and variable to be more expressive
    func runAnimationName(node2:SKNode) {

        self.run(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1),
            SKAction.run {
                node2.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2))
            },
            SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 4),
            SKAction.run {
                node2.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 3))
            }
            ]))
    }
}
```

> How does SKAction.sequence(_:) behave exactly when using SKAction.run
>   { _ }, does the next action is guarantee to be ran after the last
>   SKAction.run block's instruction executes (and what if it itself
>   perform asynchronous calls) ?

Yes, actions are executed sequentially. Also If there is an asynchronous call inside the `SKAction` run block the next `SKAction` will not wait for that asynchronous call to end.

> Bonus question: Am I right to set self as weak in closure capture
>   lists ? As I do not want it to be kept as a strong reference when
>   dismissing the game scene.

You are not using `self` inside your blocks, so you can remove the `[weak self]`.

Comment: Thanks, but the extension just hides the internal animation implementation, which is still the same. I cannot write it with something like the second code snippet I provided. I am using self inside the blocks, since node2 implicitly refers to self.node2 (I edited the code to add it).

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution is to group each SKAction.run { _ } section with an SKAction.wait(_:) with the same duration (which is ugly, the sequence call should handle it itself) :

```
extension SKNode {
    func fadeIn(withDuration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        let action = SKAction.group([
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: withDuration),
            SKAction.run {
                self.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: withDuration))
            }
        ])
        return action
    }
    //TODO: Extend for each base SKAction ...
}
```

Comment: Update: for future readers, created a GitHub repository to do so: https://github.com/michael-martinez/MMNodeActions